# Lazyloading implementation is bypassing canActivate guard in parent empty route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have implemented lazy loading in my application but due to this my parent empty route is bypassing the canActivate guard. Below is my code:

**app.routes.ts** file routes:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AppRouteGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'reports', loadChildren: './reports/reports.module#ReportsModule' }
];
```

**reports.routes.ts** file routes:

```
const reportRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ReportComponent },
  { path: 'reportProxy', component: ReportComponent },
  { path: /reportDetails/:id, component: ReportDetailComponent }
];

export const REPORT_ROUTES = RouterModule.forChild(reportRoutes);
```

AppRouteGuard is working fine if I don't implement lazy loading. If I remove the empty route in reportRoutes then it works fine.

I am unable to understand the issue here. Request you all to please help me out.

Comment: I see you don't have a `canLoad` attribute on your paths. Did you try with one ?

Comment: No, I have not used `canLoad` as I didn't require it. Also, it will require a lot of changes in my code. Thanks a lot for your suggestion, really appreciate that but right now its not feasible for me to do so many changes. Can you please suggest something else.